# Status of Batch Executed from within Python (Using Subprocess)

Tags: python, batch-file

Similar to many other questions, I have a python script based on **Windows** that will try to execute 1 or more introductory sub-processes by calling batch files and opening them in new command prompt (shell) windows.
I want to wait for these batch files to finish processing and then call an action that will use the output of these introductory processes and continue the code execution.

Based on answers, I have tried the followings with no luck. It seems to me as soon as batch file is starting execution, the sub-process returns the status 0 and stops waiting/communicating! I have all the sample codes below as well as the output. I would appreciate if anyone have any hint/tip on how this can be done if it's doable on windows ?

- Popen.wait(),
- Popen.communicate(),
- Popen.call(),
- subprocess.getstatusoutput()
- subprocess.check_call()

**python file, *start.py*:**

```
mycommand = "start test.bat"
process = subprocess.Popen(mycommand, shell=True)
    #, stdout=logfile, universal_newlines=True)
if process.poll() == None:
    print ("Pre Poll = None")
else:
    print("Pre Poll = Value")
# process.wait()
process.communicate()
if process.poll() == None:
    print ("Post Poll = None")
else:
    print("Post Poll = Value")
print ("Exit of Loop: ", process.returncode)
```

**Batch file, *start.bat*:**

```
@echo off
echo Start of Loop
echo .   
for /L %%n in (1,1,10000) do echo %%n
echo .
echo End of Loop
```

The output of Python is:

```
Pre Poll = None
Post Poll = Value
Exit of Loop:  0
```

while the batch file is still in the loop:

[image: Output of test.bat in process]

Comment: `shell = True` is your culprit. can you do your work without it?

Comment: Aah, I was thinking about either that or "start" in command which pops open a cmd window. Well, It's not desired but I guess it can be turned off as it's not essential.  Thanks, let me give it a try.